# Show all results if no option is selected

Tags: php

Below is my heavily modified code, So forgive me if you copy and paste to check my code there might be mistake as i modified it alot.

As you can see a user may input a level and then the output of SQL should show all rooms on that level

Everything works great except 1 problem. When the user makes no level input (which he is allowed to do) he should see ALL levels. So basically below he should see every room from every level.

But no matter what I do to change the SQL statement or the $_POST['level'] statement Im not able to get what I want it to do. If a user does not pick a level then no results are shown.

```
    Level: <select id="level" name="level" size="1">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value"1">1</option>
    <option value"2">2</option>
    <option value"3">3</option>
    <option value"4">4</option>
</select>
</p>


<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {


if ( empty($_POST["level"]) ) {
    NULL;
}
else {
    $level = $_POST["level"];
}

$Con=mysqli_connect(*database*);
if (!$Con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$level = mysqli_real_escape_string($Con, $level);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE level = '$level'";
$rs = mysqli_query($Con, $sql)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($Con));

?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Level</th>
    <th>Rooms</th>

</tr>

<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["level"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["rooms"]?></td>
</tr>

<?php
```

Comment: `if($level !==''){$sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE level =$level";}else{$sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms";}`

Comment: what i think that peoples are waiting for answer directly. Not interested in reading comments and do what is asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add condition for `level`

```
$levelSQL = ! empty($level) ? " WHERE level = '$level'" : '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms " . $levelSQL;
```

This condition will ensure that `level` will be checked in database only if user has selected a level.

If user did not choose a level, all records will be displayed.

Comment: Since OP is not interested, so i think why not i? your answer is correct  +10

Comment: Thank you for clarrifcation

Comment: finally, it comes to an end. He woke up